# Dynamically allocating array of structs C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm trying to make an array of structs in c, but I can't make it work. When I try to run it, the program crashes.

```
typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    char manufacturer[20];
    unsigned int price;
} product;

unsigned int stringToNr(char *numbers){
   unsigned int nr = 0; 
   unsigned int i; 
   for (i = 0; i < strlen(numbers); i ++)
   {
       nr  *= 10; nr += numbers[i] - '0'; 
   }
   return nr; 
}
```

I have a function that would print the list to a file, sometimes it reaches this function, sometimes it crashes before.

```
void printList(product *products, unsigned int nr){
    unsigned int i;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i ++){
        fprintf(f, "%s ", products[i].name);
        fprintf(f, "%s ", products[i].manufacturer);
        fprintf(f, "%d\n", products[i].price);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

I have to use a separate function to read the list from file.

```
void readList(product **products, unsigned int *nr){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char *row;
    row = malloc(sizeof(char) * 45);
    unsigned int rowLength;
    fgets(row, 45, f);
    rowLength = strlen(row);
    if (row[rowLength - 1] == '\n'){
        rowLength--;
        row[rowLength ] = '\0';
    }
    *nr = stringToNr(row);
    products = malloc((*nr) * sizeof(product*));
    unsigned int i;
    char *rowElement;
    for (i = 0; i < *nr; i ++){
        fgets(row, 45, f);
        rowElement = strtok(row, " ");
        strcpy((*products)[i].name, rowElement);
        rowElement = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcpy((*products)[i].manufacturer, rowElement);
        rowElement = strtok(NULL, " ");
        rowLength = strlen(row);
        if (row[rowLength- 1] == '\n'){
            rowLength--;
            row[rowLength] = '\0';
        }
        (*products)[i].price = stringToNr(rowElement);
    }
    free(row);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Obviously the program has more features, but those work fine.

```
int main(){
    product *products;
    unsigned int nr;
    readList(&products, &nr);
    printList(products, nr);
    free(products);
    return 0;
}
```

My input file looks like this:

```
   3
   AAA FactoryA 300
   BBB FactoryC 550
   ZZZ Factory5 100
```

Comment: What's the definition of `stringToNr`?

Comment: Use a debugger. It will save you (and us) alot of time if you learn to do that. At the very least it will immediately point you to the line of code that is triggering the crash.

Comment: Put code into the question (properly formatted) and not into the comments where it is hard to read and easy to miss.

Comment: `products = malloc((*nr) * sizeof(product*));` -> `products = malloc((*nr) * sizeof(product));`

Comment: In the `readList()` function, you are allocating only an array of `(product*` before the loop `products = malloc((*nr) * sizeof(product*));`. You shall also allocate for each item a `product` to store it ==> `products[i]=malloc(sizeof(product));`

Comment: I did what Piquard said, now it doesn't crash, but the output is the following:   0
 PBw 2130578064
  65536

Comment: @J.Piquard `products` is not to be used directly in `readList()`, but as `(*products)`.

Comment: @Unimportant [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495434/dynamically-allocating-array-of-structs-c/41495838?noredirect=1#comment70197396_41495434) mis-leads.  If `products` was a `product*`, your commnet makes sense.  But it is a `product**` and OP's `malloc()` is correct.  It is just that the result is not assigned to the right place.  Should be `*products`, not `products`.

Comment: @chux : Am I missing something here?. `product` (without `s`) is the typedef for the struct itself, so `sizeof(product*)` returns the size of a `product` pointer, not the struct size. So the code allocates space for a array of `product` pointers, not an array of `product` structs, right?

Comment: @Unimportant My [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495434/dynamically-allocating-array-of-structs-c?noredirect=1#comment70198265_41495434) was amiss concerning  "If products was a product*, your comment makes sense".  Yet  I still assert your comment misses the coding goal.  Code called `readList(&products, &nr);`, so inside the function `readList(product **products, ...)`, `*products = malloc(...);` is needed, not `products = malloc(...);`.

Comment: @chux True, an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code ignores value of `products`.

What ever `readList()` receives in `products` is overwritten with the `malloc()` call.

```
void readList(product **products, unsigned int *nr){
    ...
    // bad
    products = malloc((*nr) * sizeof(product*));
```

Instead, use `*products`.  Also  allocate by the size of the referenced variable, not by the size of the type.  Easier to code, review and maintain.

```
    *products = malloc(sizeof *(*products) * (*nr));
    if (*products == NULL) Handle_OOM();
```

---

Minor: After `fgets(row, ..., ...);` , following is not safe from a hacker exploit of reading an initial null character.

```
    rowLength = strlen(row);
    // What happens when rowLength == 0
    if (row[rowLength- 1] == '\n'){
      ...
```

Instead code could use below to rid the optional trailing `'\n'`.

```
    row[strcspn(row, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: @user3529379 Think about  what is `products`.  It is a pointer to a pointer of `product`.  Everywhere in `readList()`, code needs to use `(*products)`.  If need more info, please detail: "I can't understand" as it is too broad.

Comment: Sorry for being too vague, I don't understand why we're allocating sizeof *(*products) instead of sizeof (product) (or even sizeof *products).

Comment: @user3529379 Simplified example: Suppose `ptr` is a pointer to type  _something_ and we want `ptr` to point to `n` _something_ in memory. What is `sizeof *ptr`?  It is the size of one _something_.    `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * n)`  allocates memory for `n` _something_.  Good so far?

Comment: I think that in this case, `*products = malloc(sizeof(product) * (*nr));` will give the same result and easier to read.

Comment: @raymai97 For me, one is about the same ease to read as the other.  `*products = malloc(sizeof(product) * (*nr));` has additional  review concerns.  Was the correct type used?  That is a common mis-code.  To determine correctness, one needs to refer to the declaration of `product *products`.  With `*products = malloc(sizeof *(*products) * (*nr));` that type review is not needed.  Should type change due to code evolution  or being re-purposed, `malloc(sizeof(product) * (*nr))` needs editing.  `malloc(sizeof *(*products) * (*nr))` does not.  Easier maintenance.  Your choice.

Comment: @chux I think it depends on whether you change the variable type more often or the variable name. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @chux Yes, I think iunderstand so far. As products has already been declared  as a pointer to a product, it already has a size.

Comment: @user3529379   Now substitute `*products` for `ptr` and `*nr` for `n` --> `*products = malloc(sizeof *(*products) * (*nr));`.  Note that extra `()` added for explicitness.